# Spark vs Hive differences with ANALYZE TABLE command -

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

The ANALYZE TABLE command run from Spark on a Hive table does not give the same performance improvement as the same command issued from Hive.

For example, I have inserted a dataframe into an empty Hive table:-

```
output.write.insertInto(“XXXXXXXX”)
```

and then run the analyze table command:-

```
spark.sql("ANALYZE TABLE XXXXXXXX COMPUTE STATISTICS")
```

When I do a record count in Hive it is very slow:-

```
select count(*) from XXXXXXXX;
+-----------+
|    _c0    |
+-----------+
| 12345678  |
+-----------+
1 row selected (36.038 seconds)
```

But if I run the same analyze table command directly in Hive, performance improves:-

```
select count(*) from XXXXXXXX;
+-----------+
|    _c0    |
+-----------+
| 12345678  |
+-----------+
1 row selected (0.096 seconds)
```

Can anyone explain why this difference occurs?
Is there a workaround?

Comment: just for my understanding, you do the `ANALYZE TABLE` once via Spark API and once directly in Hive? And then you observed that querying the Hive table from Spark is faster for the second option?

Comment: did you check the query plans for both? I'm wondering whether the second option is directly used by the Hive query optimizer while the first is used by the Spark query optimizer as introduced in Spark 2.2

Comment: It also depends on the memory of your cluster for spark. also please share the engine used by hive here?is it TEZ?

Comment: Also do you have spark.sql.cbo.enabled set to True in Spark conf?

Comment: I am trying to re-write an existing Hive script in Spark. As part of testing I've noticed that running the analyze in spark.sql does not have the same affect as running the same command in Hive. The Hive engine in Tez. spark.sql.cbo.enabled is not set.

Comment: Has anyone got any suggestions on this? It seems the analyze table command can only be run in Hive if I want improved performance in Hive

Answer (score 11, accepted):

it's because spark is stupid. Spark's ANALYZE TABLE command only writes the computed statistics in a Spark-compatible format to the table properties that Hive is unaware of. Spark completely ignores the standard Hive table statistics when writing those.

if you do a

```
show create table XXXXXXXX
```

in Hive after the spark.sql("ANALYZE..") step in your query, you will see the following in the tbl_properties section:

```
TBLPROPERTIES ( 
  'numFiles'='1', 
  'numRows'='-1', 
  'rawDataSize'='-1', 
  'spark.sql.statistics.numRows'='12345678', 
  'spark.sql.statistics.totalSize'='12345678', 
  'totalSize'='12345678',
```

only after doing the same command in hive you will get the correct information:

```
TBLPROPERTIES ( 
  'numFiles'='1', 
  'numRows'='12345678', 
  'rawDataSize'='12345678', 
  'spark.sql.statistics.numRows'='12345678', 
  'spark.sql.statistics.totalSize'='12345678', 
  'totalSize'='12345678',
```

Could Spark fill the numRows and rawDataSize field correctly when computing statistics? Probably. Why does it not do it? No idea. :( Probably the spark devs are above doing optimizations for such lowly systems like Hive. (even though other frameworks like Apache Impala would also benefit from correct stats here - because Impala uses them correctly)

The only workaround is to follow up your Spark job with a corresponding hive job doing the compute statistics command, which is really ugly. :(

Comment: Are there any plans to make the Spark and Hive compatible in the future?  Any JIRA tickets for this?

Comment: In spark, if you access the table with spark.table(name), it will access the metastore for the table and have computed statistics at hand for optimizing queries.

Comment: Has Spark 3 fixed this by any chance?

Comment: No, confirmed that this is still an issue in spark 3.2.3